# Los componentes con texto con color de fondo no se repintan correctamente

Tags: java, java-swing

Estoy teniendo un problema al ponerle un color de fondo a un JTextField, y es que al ponérselo el componente se bugea y empieza a actuar extraño: al hacer click en el mismo, se va haciendo como más negro haciendo ilegible el texto, luego cuando el componente pierde el foco, pareciera que se actualiza y de tener ese color oscuro pasa a tener un color celeste sin sentido alguno. No solo me pasa con el `JTextField` sino también con un `JCheckBox`; estoy seguro que el problema ocurre al asignarle un color de fondo, porque cuando no se lo pongo no se bugea.

PD: Intenté poniendo repaints y no se solucionó.

Adjunto imágenes:

Así se ve cuando ejecuto el programa. ¿Ven el 100? Ese es el `JTextField`, ya al aparecer esta bugeado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Así queda luego de hacer click en el componente, también se puede ver el mismo bug en el `JCheckBox`:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Así aparece luego de que el componente ha perdido el foco:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
package interfaz.barraFlotante;

public final class BarraFlotante extends JPanel {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private final JLabel PLAY = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/play.png")), JLabel.CENTER);
    private final JLabel DETENER = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/detener.png")), JLabel.CENTER);
    private final JLabel PAUSA = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/pausa.png")), JLabel.CENTER);
    private final JLabel ATRAS = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/atras.png")), JLabel.CENTER);
    private final JLabel ADELANTE = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/adelante.png")), JLabel.CENTER);
    private final JLabel CONTVLT = new JLabel();
    private final JTextField CONT = new JTextField();
    private final JLabel CONTPTS = new JLabel();
    private final JPanel panelInfo2 = new JPanel();
    private final JPanel panelInfo = new JPanel();
    private final JLabel panelReloj = new JLabel();
    private final JCheckBox togglePuntos = new JCheckBox();
    private final JPanel panelPuntos = new JPanel();
    private final JComboBox<Object> PRESETS = new JComboBox<>();
    private final Color TRANSPARENTE = new Color(0, 0, 0, 30);

    public static long getSerialVersionUID() {
        return serialVersionUID;
    }

    public JLabel getPLAY() {
        return PLAY;
    }

    public JLabel getDETENER() {
        return DETENER;
    }

    public JLabel getPAUSA() {
        return PAUSA;
    }

    public JLabel getATRAS() {
        return ATRAS;
    }

    public JLabel getADELANTE() {
        return ADELANTE;
    }

    public JLabel getCONTVLT() {
        return CONTVLT;
    }

    public JTextField getCONT() {
        return CONT;
    }

    public JLabel getCONTPTS() {
        return CONTPTS;
    }

    public JPanel getPanelInfo2() {
        return panelInfo2;
    }

    public JPanel getPanelInfo() {
        return panelInfo;
    }

    public JLabel getPanelReloj() {
        return panelReloj;
    }

    public JCheckBox getTogglePuntos() {
        return togglePuntos;
    }

    public JPanel getPanelPuntos() {
        return panelPuntos;
    }

    public JComboBox getPRESETS() {
        return PRESETS;
    }

    public Color getTRANSPARENTE() {
        return TRANSPARENTE;
    }

    public BarraFlotante() {

        setBounds((int) Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize().getSize().getWidth() / 2 - 220, 0, 511, 32);
        setLayout(null);
        setOpaque(false);
        setBackground(TRANSPARENTE);
        setVisible(true);
        setPaneles();
        setOpciones();


    }

    private void setPaneles() {

        panelInfo.setBounds(200, 3, 83, 26);
        panelInfo.setOpaque(true);
        panelInfo.setBackground(new Color(0, 0, 0, 15));
        panelInfo.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.BLACK));
        panelInfo.setLayout(null);
        add(panelInfo);

        panelInfo2.setBackground(new Color(0, 0, 0, 15));
        panelInfo2.setBounds(288, 3, 55, 26);
        panelInfo2.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.BLACK));
        panelInfo2.setLayout(null);
        add(panelInfo2);

        panelReloj.setBounds(348, 3, 50, 26);
        panelReloj.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.BLACK));
        panelReloj.setOpaque(true);
        panelReloj.setBackground(new Color(0, 0, 0, 15));
        panelReloj.setFont(new Font("Dialog", 1, 12));
        panelReloj.setText("00.00.00");
        add(panelReloj);

        panelPuntos.setBounds(403, 3, 50, 26);
        panelPuntos.setBackground(new Color(0, 0, 0, 15));
        panelPuntos.setVisible(true);
        panelPuntos.setLayout(null);
        panelPuntos.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.BLACK));
        add(panelPuntos);

    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    private void setOpciones() {

        PLAY.setBounds(1, 0, 30, 30);
        PLAY.setVisible(true);
        add(PLAY);

        PAUSA.setBounds(30, 1, 30, 30);
        add(PAUSA);

        DETENER.setBounds(60, 1, 30, 30);
        add(DETENER);

        ATRAS.setBounds(464, 1, 20, 30);
        add(ATRAS);

        ADELANTE.setBounds(488, 1, 20, 30);
        add(ADELANTE);

        PRESETS.addItem("ASd");
        PRESETS.addItem("prueba2");
        PRESETS.setBounds(96, 4, 99, 23);
        add(PRESETS);

        JLabel img = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/ciclo.png")));
        img.setBounds(4, 6, 20, 16);
        panelInfo.add(img);

        CONTVLT.setFont(new Font("Dialog", 1, 12));
        CONTVLT.setText("100 /");
        CONTVLT.setBounds(img.getWidth() + 7, 6, CONTVLT.getText().length() * 6, 15);
        panelInfo.add(CONTVLT);

        CONT.setBackground(new Color(0, 0, 0, 50));
        CONT.setText("100");
        CONT.setBounds(CONTVLT.getWidth() + 28, 8, CONT.getText().length() * 8 - 2, 10);
        CONT.setBorder(null);
        CONT.setFont(new Font("Dialog", 1, 12));
        panelInfo.add(CONT);

        JLabel img1 = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/contador.png")), JLabel.LEFT);
        img1.setBounds(1, 0, 30, 26);
        Redimensionador.iniciar(img1, 30, 26);
        panelInfo2.add(img1);

        CONTPTS.setFont(new Font("Dialog", 1, 12));
        CONTPTS.setText("50");
        CONTPTS.setBounds(32, 3, 14, 20);
        panelInfo2.add(CONTPTS);

        togglePuntos.setBounds(1, 5, 46, 17);
        togglePuntos.setBackground(new Color(0, 0, 0, 5));
        togglePuntos.setText("Ver");
        panelPuntos.add(togglePuntos);

        JSeparator grabacion = new JSeparator();

        grabacion.setOrientation(1);
        grabacion.setVisible(true);
        grabacion.setBounds(90, 6, 30, 20);
        grabacion.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
        add(grabacion);

        JSeparator flechas = new JSeparator();

        flechas.setOrientation(1);
        flechas.setVisible(true);
        flechas.setBounds(458, 6, 30, 20);
        flechas.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
        add(flechas);

        repaint();

    }

    private void InitEventos() {

        BarraEventos eventos = new BarraEventos(this);

    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Dimension arcs = new Dimension(15, 15);
        int width = getWidth();
        int height = getHeight();
        Graphics2D graphics = (Graphics2D) g;
        graphics.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);

        //Draws the rounded opaque panel with borders.
        graphics.setColor(getBackground());
        graphics.fillRoundRect(0, 0, width - 1, height - 1, 29, 29);//paint background
        graphics.setColor(getForeground());
        graphics.drawRoundRect(0, 0, width - 1, height - 1, 29, 29);//paint border

    }

}
```

Comment: Si evitas usar los colores alfa y creas una variable de Color para todos los componentes que quieras que tengan ese mismo Background se soluciona, no creo que necesites usar colores transparentes para hacer que los componentes tengan el mismo color de fondo que el componente Padre (BarraFlotante)

Comment: Hola gracias por tu comentario, si iba a ponerle el mismo color a todos los componentes, pero cuando les puse el mismo rgb, no coincidía su color en la barra, o eran más claros o más oscuros, por eso para algunos componentes tuve que cambiar el rgb, por otra parte a que te refieres con colores alfa?? Como verás en la imagen todos los componentes tienen el mismo color, sin embargo,en el código, el rgb de de algunos componentes no es el mismo

Comment: Hablaba del canal Alfa, estas usando RGBA, no RBG, tus componentes tienen por ejemplo un background 0,0,0,5 (RED, GREEN, BLUE, ALPHA), los colores mas claros o oscuros se deben a que la transparencia se superpone entre los componentes de abajo, podías usar un color general para todos y a los que necesites cambiar vas variando el color RBG

Comment: Hola si efectivamente era eso, ya lo solucione, muchas gracias

Comment: @IgnacioInzerilli no olvides ponerlo como respuesta, y [acéptala](/help/accepted-answer) cuando transcurra el tiempo mínimo.

Comment: Hola padaleiana como has respondido con un comentario, y no como respuesta a mí pregunta, no puedo marcar como solucionada